# How to deploy JavascriptMVC?

Tags: deployment, javascriptmvc

I've started using javascriptmvc (http://javascriptmvc.com/index.html).

The total size of javascriptmvc itself (without my app) is about 23mb.

When I deploy my app with javascriptmvc, do i need all of them?

or

Do I only need /steal/steal.production.js and my own app?

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=compressing, I'd say you only need the compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the steal.production.js, production.css, production.js.